# Create MessageHeader without serializing XML Content

Tags: wcf, serialization, soap, .net-3.5

I'm trying to add a timestamp to the headers of my request to a 3th party Java webservice that looks like :

```
<wsu:Timestamp xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" wsu:Id="Timestamp-1120">
    <wsu:Created>2013-03-05T07:18:42.672Z</wsu:Created>
    <wsu:Expires>2013-03-05T07:23:42.672Z</wsu:Expires>
</wsu:Timestamp>
```

I'm using this code -

```
Message request;    

// TESTVALUE
string content = "<Created>2013-03-05T07:18:42.672Z</Created><Expires>2013-03-05T07:23:42.672Z</Expires>";

MessageHeader msgHeader = MessageHeader.CreateHeader("Timestamp", "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd", content);
request.Headers.Add(msgHeader);
```

Problem is that it serializes my content to this and I have no clue how I can fix this -

```
    <Timestamp xmlns="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
         &lt;Created&gt;2013-03-05T07:18:42.672Z&lt;/Created&gt;&lt;Expires&gt;2013-03-05T07:23:42.672Z&lt;/Expires&gt;
    </Timestamp>
```

I tried to add two `XElement`'s but problem is I can only provide one of these..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that WCF is encoding what you have specified as content *within* the header.  You can just create a custom "Timestamp" class to deal with the contents of the Timestamp, instead of using a string.  You can probably use a `DataContract` to serialize it, but worst-case you'll have to resort to custom XML serialization in the new class.

Comment: Where do I need to apply the DataContract? (I don't have access to the service)

Comment: You would create a class for the Timestamp, with properties for the two dates.  You should then be able to give them names to match the XML element names you want.  Apply the DataContract to Timestamp and DataMember to the two dates and it *should* work.  I'm on a tablet right now, though, so I can't prove it.